# Vue v-if doesn't seem to be working in a wrapper vue

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to hide my website header whenever I am not logged in and show my header when I am logged in.
I have a wrapper vue called App.vue in there I have the header with the binding to `loggedIn`.

```
  <div id="app">
    <Header v-if="loggedIn"></Header>
    <component :is="currentComponent" @triggerNotification="triggerNotification"/>
 </div>
```

`loggedIn` is part of my data

```
  data() {
    return {
      loggedIn: localStorage.getItem('loggedIn'),
    }
  },
```

Now every time I move from page to page I wanna make sure that the header is going to be shown or not depending on the `loggedIn` attribute.

```
  watch: {
    currentComponent: 'setLoggedIn',
  },
  methods: {
    setLoggedIn() {
      this.loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
    }
  }
```

The `setLoggedIn` function is triggered every time I move from page to page and `loggedIn` is set correctly every time, but for some reason my header does not disappear at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, localStorage saves `loggedIn` as a String, hence it is always recognised as `true` by the `v-if`, simply casting to Boolean `localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')` did the trick :)

`localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')` **--->** `localStorage.getItem('loggedIn) === 'true'`